# How to pass data.frame into SQL "IN" condition using R?

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

I am reading list of values from CSV file in R, and trying to pass the values into IN condition of SQL(dbGetQuery). Can some one help me out with this?

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(dbplyr)
library(tibble)
library(DBI)
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)


jdbcDriver <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath="C://Users/********/Oracle_JDBC/ojdbc6.jar")

jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:oracle:thin:Rahul@//Host/DB", "User_name", "Password") 

## Setting working directory for the data
setwd("C:\\Users\\**********\\Desktop")

## reading csv file into data frame
pii<-read.csv("sample.csv")

pii

 PII_ID
S0094-5765(17)31236-5
S0094-5765(17)31420-0
S0094-5765(17)31508-4
S0094-5765(17)31522-9
S0094-5765(17)30772-5
S0094-5765(17)30773-7

PII_ID1<-dbplyr::build_sql(pii$PII_ID)

PII_ID1

<SQL> ('S0094-5765(17)31236-5', 'S0094-5765(17)31420-0', 'S0094-5765(17)31508-4', 'S0094-5765(17)31522-9', 'S0094-5765(17)30772-5', 'S0094-5765(17)30773-7')


Data<-dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, "SELECT ARTICLE_ID FROM JRBI_OWNER.JRBI_ARTICLE_DIM WHERE PII_ID in  ?",(PII_ID1))
```

Expected:

```
ARTICLE_ID
12345
23456
12356
14567
13456
```

Actual result:

```
[1] ARTICLE_ID
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: can you do `query = paste0("SELECT ARTICLE_ID FROM JRBI_OWNER.JRBI_ARTICLE_DIM WHERE PII_ID IN ", PII_ID1)` and then try `Data<-dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, query)` ?

Comment: In general, when using the `IN` condition, I'd prefer to operate a join. Use `dbWriteTable` to create a temporary table with the `PII_ID` values and then operate a join. In this way you don't need to build and send huge queries.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code you pass in the second argument to `dbGetQuery` is just a text string, hence you can construct this using `paste` or equivalents.

You are after something like the following:

```
in_clause <- paste0("('", paste0(pii$PII_ID, collapse = "', '"), "')")

sql_text <- paste0("SELECT ARTICLE_ID 
              FROM JRBI_OWNER.JRBI_ARTICLE_DIM
              WHERE PII_ID IN ", in_clause)

 data <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_text)
```

However, the exact form of the first `paste0` depends on the format of `PII_ID` (I have assumed it is text) and how this format is represented in sql (I have assumed single quotes).

Be sure to check `sql_text` is valid SQL before passing it to `dbGetQuery`.

IMPORTANT: This approach is only suitable when `pii` contains a small number of values (I recommend fewer than 10). If `pii` contains a large number of values your query will be very large and will run very slowly. If you have many values in `pii` then a better approach would be a join or semi-join as per @nicola's comment.