# GROUP BY ... HAVING in dbplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis, dbplyr

How do I perform the GROUP BY ... HAVING query using dbplyr in dplyr?

I have a list of IDs and I have to group by IDs which are not in this list.
Is there a way I can directly execute the query with `tbl()`, if not what is the dplyr verb for the same?

Using `group_by_if` function from dplyr doesn't seem to do it.

I want to execute something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM TBL 
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2001
GROUP BY COL1 HAVING COL2 NOT IN ID_LIST
```

where `ID_LIST` is an R vector

Comment: Use a `filter` before performing the `group_by`?

Comment: All the filter functions get converted to where queries or it becomes a complicated nested query

Answer (score 1):

For the example you have given, it is not clear to me how

```sql
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2001
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING COL2 NOT IN ID_LIST
```

Is different from

```sql
SELECT * FROM TBL
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2001
AND COL2 NOT IN ID_LIST
GROUP BY COL1
```

Hence @Rohit's suggestion of applying a filter is an effective solution.

`HAVING` largely operates the same way as `WHERE` but after aggregation with the added feature that you can use aggregators in the `HAVING` clause. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768987/what-is-the-difference-of-using-having-vs-a-subquery). But in this case you are not applying aggregators in the `HAVING` clause so you should be free to use a `WHERE` clause instead.

Regarding the nested SQL queries that dbplyr produces. It might seem counter intuitive given the usual emphasis on clean, human-readable code, but for dbplyr auto-generated queries I recommend not worrying about the quality of the machine generated code. It is written by a machine and it is (mostly) read by a machine, so its human readability is less important.

Efficiency could be a concern with many layers of nesting. However, in [2017-06-09](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html) dbplyr was given a basic SQL optimiser. I have not found (though I have not tested extensively) nested auto-generated queries to perform significantly worse than non-nested user written queries. But if performance is critical, you probably want to build your SQL query manually by `paste`-ing together text strings in R.

One final thought - the length of `ID_LIST` is also important to consider. It is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570746/how-to-pass-data-frame-into-sql-in-condition-using-r) question.