# Use of dbplyr for in-database processing vs directly writing SQL code

Tags: r, dbplyr

We are planning to explore use of dbplyr for Snowflake and would like get more insight.

1. dbplyr converting SQL code for in-database processing will be equally efficient than directly writing SQL code ?
2. does dbplyr supports complex multi-level (at least 3 level) sub-query ?

Over question is that ....Does it make sense to use dbplyr for enterprise level application for big data analysis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbplyr works by translating dplyr code into SQL. This has some advantages:

- elegance of R tools
- access to other parts of R programming language (e.g. loops, plots, packages)
- the same code can be translated to a different database type

and some disadvantages:

- not all R commands have translations defined
- some restrictions on how R code can be written for translation
- presentation of translated commands is less elegant than human written SQL code
- error messages in R are not always sufficient to debug problems that occur in the database

Whether it is right for your application is a practical question you will need to test.

Regarding sub-queries:

- dbplyr uses sub-queries throughout its translation, but not in the same way developers write sub-queries
- SQL has an upper limit on the number of sub-queries it can handle, if you write your dplyr code badly then you can encounter this limit

Other answers you might find relevant:

- [Inserting your own SQL queries into dbplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65165152/7742981)
- [What should you expect of auto-generated queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934645/7742981)
- [Layers of nesting and readability of queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56451949/7742981)